# Using Python for .NET for Python3.4 in visual studio

Tags: c#, python, .net, visual-studio, python.net

I am trying to use Python for .NET embedding python code in a c# project. I am using Visual Studio under Windows environment.

I did install Python for .NET by `pip install pythonnet` in cmd. Those 3 demos in repo runs with no issue. Then I use a winform project to call `PythonEngine.Initialize();`. It throw an exception that

> 'Unable to load DLL'python35':The specified module could not be found.

I did follow the guide on http://pythonnet.github.io/, but still it doesn't work.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: read this: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX#common-errors

Comment: @denfromufa I did try the solution(Set the environment path for "PATH" and "PYTHONHOME") in the common error. It still not working. For more information, the python is a 3.4.4 64 bit version which is installed with the Plaxis 3D 2017 installation.

Comment: Based on the error you are using pythonnet for python 3.5 - i have no idea why you say Python 3.4.

Comment: In the development computer, I did install multiple Python for testing purpose. E.g. PyQt (Python 3.5), Python 3.6.5 and 3.6.6. But I type python in CMD, it show Python 3.4.4.